# I can't press login as it doesn't work; it basically does nothing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

vrGui = Tk()

vrGui.configure(bg="Yellow")

vrGui.title("Spelling Bee")

vrGui.geometry("500x500+500+350")

label = Label(vrGui,text = "Student Login",font=("Britannic Bold", 18,"bold"))

label.configure (bg="Yellow")
label.place(x=160, y=45)



user = StringVar()
passw = StringVar()

with open("student.txt",mode="r",encoding="utf-8") as inFile:
    student = inFile.read().splitlines()



def enter():
    def check_user():

 username = vrBox1.get()

 password = vRBoX.get()

if username in student:

import starttest

            entry1= Label(vrGui,text="Logged in")

            entry1.place(x=250,y=250)

 elif username not in student:

            entry1= Label(vrGui,text="Incorrect")

            entry1.place(x=250,y=250)



enter =Button(vrGui,text="Login",width=20,height=1,command=enter)

enter.place(x=200,y=240)    

def Homescreen():

    vrGui.destroy()

    import startingpage

bkBut=Button(vrGui,text="Back to Homepage",width=20,height=1,command=Homescreen)

bkBut.place(x=200,y=280)

info_label=Label(vrGui, text="Enter Username and Password and press login", bg="yellow")

info_label.place(x=100,y= 150)

vrLabel = Label (text="Username", bg="yellow")

vrLabel.place(x=125,y=180)

vrBox1 = Entry()

vrBox1.place(x=200,y=180)


vRLabe2 = Label (text="Password", bg="yellow")

vRLabe2.place(x=125,y=210)

vRBox = Entry()

vRBox.place(x=200,y=210)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should definitely throw some errors, but I'll assume you retyped it here and just made some indentation and spelling mistakes, if it just does nothing when you press the enter button, and this is your error: You're never calling the function `check_user()`. If you don't need it as a function, just delete it and make that part of your code run under your `enter()` function:

```
def enter():
    username = vrBox1.get()
    password = vRBoX.get()

    if username in student:
        import starttest
        entry1= Label(vrGui,text="Logged in")
        entry1.place(x=250,y=250)
    elif username not in student:
        entry1= Label(vrGui,text="Incorrect")
        entry1.place(x=250,y=250)
```

Comment: hi mate thank you so much but it say vRBox is not defined?? petem

Comment: That's because you spell it vRBox once and vRBoX the other time. Note the X